# Split collection into sub collections in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have an array containing an unknown number of items that I would like to split into separate arrays so that each separate array contains no more than 4 items. What is the best way to do this in Groovy? Thanks!

Comment: As of groovy 1.8.6 you can use the [collate method](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5283) on Lists

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We had this here: [How to split a list into equal sized lists in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924395/groovy-built-in-to-split-an-array-into-equal-sized-subarrays)

I came up with this:

```
List.metaClass.partition = { size ->
  def rslt = delegate.inject( [ [] ] ) { ret, elem ->
    ( ret.last() << elem ).size() >= size ? ret << [] : ret
  }
  !rslt.last() ? rslt[ 0..-2 ] : rslt
}

def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].partition( 4 )
```

Which should give you:

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ] ]
```

### Update!

With Groovy 1.8.6+ you can use `list.collate( 4 )` to get the same result

Comment: @RaffiM With Groovy 1.8.6+ [you can use `list.collate( 4 )`](http://blog.bloidonia.com/post/18073244930/whats-new-in-groovy-1-8-6-the-collate-method) to get the same result :-)

Comment: In a large application, where is the best place to define the `partition` method? Making it part of the `List.metaClass` is not practical since it only exists in the context of the groovy class where it's defined.

Comment: @RaffiM I would upgrade groovy and use `collate` ;-) failing that, if you add it at the startup cycle of your app. Or rewrite it as a category?

Comment: We're not using that Groovy version just yet...can the partition method be standalone, like a utility function? What parts would have to change?

Comment: @RaffiM there's another functional version [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2926548/6509)

Answer (score 6):

Answer by tim_yates is cool, but it throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on empty lists (for example: `[].partition(4)`). This can be fixed in this way:

```
List.metaClass.partition = {size ->
    if (!delegate)
        return []

    def rslt = delegate.inject([[]]) {ret, elem ->
        (ret.last() << elem).size() >= size ? (ret << []) : ret
    }
    !rslt.last() ? rslt[0..-2] : rslt
}

assert [].partition(4) == []
assert [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].partition(4) == [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: good catch! Could also turn last line into `!rslt[ 0 ] ? [] : !rslt.last() ? rslt[ 0..-2 ] : rslt`

Comment: @Rorick I tested the above with a list, and it works without changing a single thing in that function, does Groovy treat Lists and Arrays equally?

Comment: Mostly but there can be differences. For instance, list has no `length` property while arrays have. But in most cases arrays behave in the same way as lists.

Answer (score 4):

Since Groovy 1.8.6, you can use collate:

```
def letters = 'a'..'g'
assert letters.collate(3) == [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g']]

def letters = 'a'..'g'
assert letters.collate(3) == [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g']]
```

Credit to Mrhaki's Groovy goodness series:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/groovy-goodness-collate-list-into-sub.html