# How to 'Slice' a Collection in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a collection of objects that I want to break up into a collection of collections, where each sequential group of 3 elements is in one collection.
For example, if I have

```
def l = [1,4,2,4,5,9]
```

I want to turn this into:

```
def r = [[1,4,2], [4,5,9]]
```

I'm doing it now by iterating over the collection and breaking it up.. but I then need to pass those 'groups' into a parallelized function that processes them.. It would be nice to eliminate this O(n) pre-processing work and just say something like

```
l.slice(3).collectParallel { subC -> process(subC) }
```

I've found the step method on the Range class, but it looks like that only acts on the indices.  Any clever ideas?

Update:
I don't think this is a duplicate of the referenced link, although it's very close.  As suggested below, it's more of the iterator-type thing I'm looking for.. the sub-collections will then be passed into a GPars collectParallel.  Ideally I wouldn't need to allocate an entire new collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy built-in to split an array into equal sized subarrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924395/groovy-built-in-to-split-an-array-into-equal-sized-subarrays)

Comment: I agree that this isn't an exact duplicate because of the lazy nature of what you're looking for.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a slice, but rather a collation.  I thought a slice was something  more like this:  http://www.webquills.net/web-development/perl/perl-5-hash-slices-can-replace.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check out groovy 1.8.6. There is a new collate method on List.

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
assert list.collate(4) == [[1, 2, 3, 4]] // gets you everything   
assert list.collate(2) == [[1, 2], [3, 4]] //splits evenly
assert list.collate(3) == [[1, 2, 3], [4]] // won't split evenly, remainder in last list.
```

Take a look at the [Groovy List documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html) for more info because there are a couple of other params that give you some other options, including dropping the remainder.

As far as your parallel processing goes, you can cruise through the lists with [gpars](http://gpars.codehaus.org/).

```
def list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
GParsPool.withPool {
  list.collate(2).eachParallel {
     println it
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're currently copying the elements from the original collection into the sub-collections. For more suggestions along those lines, checkout the answers to the following question: [Split collection into sub collections in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3147537/33836)

It sounds like what you're instead looking for is a way for the sub-collections to effectively be a view into the original collection. If that's the case, check out the [List.subList() method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29). You could either loop over the indices from 0 to size() in increments of 3 (or whatever slice size you choose) or you could get fancier and build an Iterable/List which would hide the details from the caller. Here's an implementation of the latter, inspired by [Ted's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873594/how-to-slice-a-collection-in-groovy/5877834#5877834).

```
class Slicer implements Iterator {
  private List backingList
  private int sliceSize
  private int index

  Slicer(List backingList, int sliceSize) {
    this.backingList = backingList
    this.sliceSize = sliceSize
  }

  Object next() {
    if (!hasNext()) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException()
    }

    def ret
    if (index + sliceSize <= backingList.size()) {
      ret = backingList.subList(index, index+sliceSize)
    } else if (hasNext()) {
      ret = backingList.subList(index, backingList.size())
    }
    index += sliceSize
    return ret
  }

  boolean hasNext() {
    return index < backingList.size()
  }

  void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException() //I'm lazy ;)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the inf- - you're right, it's more of the 'view' that I want to create.. there's no need to re-allocate any new objects.  The approach in Michael's link above works just fine.. just as my existing code does.  This 'Iterable' implementation sounds about right - wondering how much code it would take to do - need to define a new implementation of Iterable? Subclass Iterator?

Comment: I think you might have an off-by-one error in your implementation of hasNext(). Try with lists with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 elements and a sliceSize of 4.

Comment: @jabley You're right! I'm not sure what led me to put that in there. I'll go remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I like both solutions but here is a slightly improved version of the first solution that I like very much:

```
class Slicer implements Iterator {
private List backingList
private int sliceSize
private int index

Slicer(List backingList, int sliceSize) {
  this.backingList = backingList;
  int ss = sliceSize;

  // negitive sliceSize = -N means, split the list into N equal (or near equal) pieces  
  if( sliceSize < 0) {
      ss = -sliceSize;
      ss = (int)((backingList.size()+ss-1)/ss);
  }
  this.sliceSize = ss
}

Object next() {
  if (!hasNext()) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException()
  }

  def ret = backingList.subList(index, Math.min(index+sliceSize , backingList.size()) );
  index += sliceSize
  return ret
  }

  boolean hasNext() {
    return index < backingList.size() - 1
  }

  void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException() //I'm lazy ;)
  }

  List asList() {
    this.collect { new ArrayList(it) }
  }

  List flatten() {
    backingList.asImmutable()
  }

}

// ======== TESTS

    def a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    assert  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] == a;
    assert [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]] ==  new Slicer(a,2).asList(); 
    assert [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8]] == (new Slicer(a,3)).collect { it } // alternative to asList but inner items are subList
    assert [3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 8, 7] == ((new Slicer(a,3)).collect { it.reverse() } ).flatten()

    // show flatten iterator
    //new Slicer(a,2).flattenEach { print it }
    //println ""

    // negetive slice into N pieces, in this example we split it into 2 pieces
    assert [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]] ==  new Slicer(a,-2).collect { it as List }  // same asList
    assert [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]] == new Slicer(a,-3).asList()
    //assert a == (new Slicer(a,3)).flattenCollect { it } 
    assert [9..10, 19..20, 29..30] == ( (new Slicer(1..30,2)).findAll { slice -> !(slice[1] % 10) } )
    assert [[9, 10], [19, 20], [29, 30]] == ( (new Slicer(1..30,2)).findAll { slice -> !(slice[1] % 10) }.collect { it.flatten() } )

    println( (new Slicer(1..30,2)).findAll { slice -> !(slice[1] % 10) } )
    println( (new Slicer(1..30,2)).findAll { slice -> !(slice[1] % 10) }.collect { it.flatten() } )
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything built in to do exactly what you want, but if we `@Delegate` calls to the native lists's iterator, we can write our own class that works just like an Iterator that returns the chunks you're looking for:

```
class Slicer {
    protected Integer sliceSize 
    @Delegate Iterator iterator

    Slicer(objectWithIterator, Integer sliceSize) {
        this.iterator = objectWithIterator.iterator()
        this.sliceSize = sliceSize
    }

    Object next() {
        List currentSlice = []
        while(hasNext() && currentSlice.size() < sliceSize) {
            currentSlice << this.iterator.next()
        }
        return currentSlice
    }
}

assert [[1,4,2], [4,5,9]] == new Slicer([1,4,2,4,5,9], 3).collect { it }
```

Because it has all of the methods that a normal Iterator does, you get the groovy syntactic sugar methods for free with lazy evaluation on anything that has an `iterator()` method, like a range:

```
assert [5,6] == new Slicer(1..100, 2).find { slice -> slice.first() == 5 }

assert [[9, 10], [19, 20], [29, 30]] == new Slicer(1..30, 2).findAll { slice -> !(slice[1] % 10) }
```

Comment: I like your solution, but it still feels like making copies rather than having sub-lists that are views of the original list. I'm trying to figure out if there's some way to combine your approach with List.subList().

Comment: I might not be understanding your comment, but the code above isn't making a copy, it's creating a lazy list iterator that's delegating to the original lists native iterator.  No list copying is happening.  I'm not sure how you could create a lazy version of your list that something like collectParallel could use.  Lots of non-lazy versions (with something like inject, but not lazy.  If you come up with something, I'd like to see it :).

Comment: My thoughts finally coalesced. Your solution is perfect when all you know about the backing object is that it's an Iterable. However, if you know that it's a RandomAccessList (such as an ArrayList), you could instead maintain a running index in Slicer and have your next methods return `backingList.subList(index, index+sliceSize)`. It wouldn't make much of a difference when sliceSize is 3, but for 1000, you'd avoid allocating space for each slice and the time spent adding the items into the slice. Make more sense?

Comment: Yep, I get what you're saying now.  You're not talking about worrying that there's a full copy of the list, but a copy of the subset items that are in the slice section.  You're asking for an optimization that just returns one item at a time to the caller in the view.  You'd need to return a proxy object that also delegates the getAt to the original list.

Comment: That's basically what I was getting at. See my edited answer for a concrete example.