# Groovy, collating list causes concurrentmodification exception

Tags: arrays, list, groovy, iteration, concurrentmodification

Still learning the ropes with Groovy, this problem has tripped me up since last night. Not sure why it's throwing concurrentmod exception...(Java 1.6, Groovy 1.8.4)

I have a list of keys...
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]`

I collate the list using a custom function `partitionList(keys,3)` I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924395/groovy-built-in-to-split-an-array-into-equal-sized-subarrays/2926548#2926548) (can't use java.List.Collate, not on 1.8.6)

Now I've got a list of lists...
`[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13]]`

If the number of sub-lists created is odd, I remove the last sub list `[12,13]` and redistribute its keys amongst the other sub lists starting in order, creating...

`[[0,1,2,12],[3,4,5,13],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]]`

The exception occurs when iterating the values of the last sub list. Not sure why since I'm iterating a list and changing an entirely different list in that loop...

**UPDATE:**

Interesting....if I don't use the `paritionList()` function, replacing
`def keyRanges = partitionList( keys, 3)`
with an explicit list of lists...
`def keyRanges = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13]]`
the problem disappears. So I'm lead to believe the partitionList() function is doing something that's causing the exception

```
class CollateListTest {

    static main(args) {    
        def keys = (0..13).toList()

        //partition the keys into a list of lists 
        def keyRanges = partitionList( keys, 3)
        println 'Key range sets...'
        for( keyRange in keyRanges)
            println keyRange

        //if odd number of partitions, 
        //remove last sub list and redistribute values over other lists
        if( (keyRanges.size() % 2) != 0){
            def lastKeyRange = keyRanges.remove( keyRanges.size() - 1 )
            println 'removed range: ' + lastKeyRange

                    // ** EXCEPTION HERE **         
            lastKeyRange.eachWithIndex{ k, index ->
                println 'adding: ' + k
                keyRanges[ index % keyRanges.size()].add( k)
            }
        }
    }

    //from stackoverflow.com/questions/2924395/
    static def partitionList(list, size) {
        def partitions = []
        int partitionCount = list.size() / size

        partitionCount.times { partitionNumber ->
            def start = partitionNumber * size
            def end = start + size - 1
            partitions << list[start..end]
        }

        if (list.size() % size) partitions << list[partitionCount * size..-1]
        return partitions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `partitionList` method you're using splits up the list with [List.getAt(Range)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#getAt%28groovy.lang.Range%29).  This returns a view into the original list, but doesn't copy the data, so any modifications to the sublist also affect the original.

This means that `lastKeyRange` shares data with `keyRanges`, and that adding to one of the sublists indirectly affects the sublist you are iterating over.  Rather than modifying the sublist, just create a new one.  For example:

```
if( (keyRanges.size() % 2) != 0){
    def lastKeyRange = keyRanges.remove( keyRanges.size() - 1 )
    println 'removed range: ' + lastKeyRange

    lastKeyRange.eachWithIndex{ k, index ->
        println 'adding: ' + k
        def newRange = []
        newRange.addAll(keyRanges[ index % keyRanges.size()])
        newRange.add(k)
        keyRanges[ index % keyRanges.size()] = newRange

    }
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully, had a feeling it had something to do with a handle to the original list...thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to implement this enhancement in partitionList() itself? Would make for a cleaner, more efficient, solution. just wondering