# extract pairs from groovy list

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy.

Is there way to get elements from list as pairs.

```
options_str = "test_suite test_suite_name email emialid job_name test_job"
split_option = options_str.split()
println split_option
```

Current output:

```
[test_suite, test_suite_name, email, emialid, job_name, test_job]
```

Expected output:

```
[[test_suite, test_suite_name], [email, emialid], [job_name, test_job]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
options_str = "test_suite test_suite_name email emialid job_name test_job"
split_option = options_str.split()
println split_option.collate(2)
```

Comment: after I put together my question, I found answer so thought of posting it.

Comment: collate is deprecated for list/array. In case you need such function refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2926548/3720085

Comment: collate is deprecated for list/array. In case you need such function refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2926548/3720085